# H2 Database (Server) TCP connection timeout & connection pooling

Tags: tcp, jvm, h2, connection-timeout

I started the server and then application on a certain IP and Port from scratch (no dulpicate servers or port already used). The application was crashing due to java-lang-OutOfMemory error, saying that no new thread can be created. I  allocated JVM 4G memory, and now that error is silent. But, now afterwards starting the client is crashing again. It runs for about 10-15 seconds and crash with SocketTimeoutException. Here is the trace

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out: MYIPADDRESS" [90067-172]
   at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
   at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:407)
   at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:295)
   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:105)
   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:90)
   at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
   at com.org.tseries.simulator.IPEmailSeriesTestDriver.shootH2(IPEmailSeriesTestDriver.java:201)
   at com.org.tseries.simulator.IPEmailSeriesTestDriver.processSimulator(IPEmailSeriesTestDriver.java:160)
   at com.org.tseries.simulator.IPEmailSeriesTestDriver.main(IPEmailSeriesTestDriver.java:98)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
   at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:119)
   at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:100)
   at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:95)
   at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:403)
... 14 more
```

It is crashing when I run the client from terminal but when I ran the same client from STS (eclipse based IDE), it didnt crashed. Any setting or flag I need to add while running the client?

**UPDATED:** It is solved with appending AUTORECONNECT=TRUE in connection string. More details here, h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_reconnect

But now, I am interested in making a connection pool at Server end that allows different TCP clients to connect. The server shall serve the clients from the connection pool instead of clients reconnecting again. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Try open `C:\Users\Superuser\db.lock.db`. If this database already running you will see IP and port. Then in console type command `netstat -ano`. It will display all processes. Find PID of proccess that holds IP and port you found in .db file. Than you may kill this proccess using Task Manager or with help of command in console.

Another way: check all configs. You may use different IP in different configs. Synchronize this